# Use Google managed ssl certificate with dockerized uwsgi app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, https, terraform, uwsgi, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using Terraform to deploy the infrastructure for my app.
One of the modules is this: https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-lb-http to create a Load Balancer with a registered domain and everything.

My app works perfect in HTTP mode, but once I want to use SSL, TF creates the certificates on GCP and redirects all traffic to HTTPS.

The problem is that the app is not responding and getting 503 all the time with the error `malformed HTTP request`

I guess I have to run uwsgi inside the container in HTTPS mode but for that I need the certificate and private key files to be available locally inside the container.

According to GCP support, right now we cannot download these files.

Is there any solution or workaround that I can do?

Comment: If you are using a Google HTTP(S) load balancer, the backend is configured only for HTTP. That way you do not need certificates on the backend. However, if you require full encryption, you can use a self signed certificate on the backend.

Comment: So, you're saying the backend can stay HTTP and it should work?

Comment: Yes, you can configure backends to use either HTTP or HTTPS or both. The load balancer supports each configuration type.

Comment: @JohnHanley this actually worked. If you post it as answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: Give the award to @paumanel since he did post the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by John, if you want to configure your application for HTTPS traffic using a Google Cloud External HTTP/S Load Balancer, you can keep the [backend using HTTP](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#protocol_to_the_backends) meanwhile the external clients can still connect using HTTPS to the Load Balancer Frontend.

This would look something like this:

Client --- (HTTPS) ---> Load Balancer --- (HTTP) ---> Backend

If you want to also [encrypt the private traffic from the Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/encryption-to-the-backends) to your docker application, you will need to use your own self signed certificate on the application itself.